# Is it valid to pass a non-standard engine to uniform_int_distribution?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

When using VS2013, it appears that `std::uniform_int_distribution::operator()` just requires that the `Generator` template argument have a `typedef`ed `result_type`, `static` `min` and `max` functions, and an overloaded `operator()`.

I've got a class that wraps a random number engine defined in the STL, and externally there's no difference between my wrapper class and the internally wrapped engine. I would like to use my wrapper class as the `Generator` parameter, but I don't know if the standard specifies that only the known generators are valid, or if it leaves the implementation of `uniform_int_distribution` unspecified and I can't rely on VS2013's implementation details.

Comment: post code please. As long as you recreate what the engine passes to the uniform_int_distribution it doesn't care frankly. It just modifies the values from the random num gen. passed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard sets out the requirements for an `Engine` in 26.5.1.4, [rand.req.eng], and the various distributions require that you pass them something that meets those requirements.